# MongooseJS - find() $gt condition case insensitive (Previous title: condition on string not working as expected )

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to query a collection containing user data, imposing $gt condition on a string field, but when I query it return an empty result, while using an empty $gt condition, as `{name: {$gt:''}}` it returns the whole dataset, as i would expect.

The model schema:

```
var patientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String, required: true
    },
    surname: {
        type: String, required: true
    },
    birth: {
        type: Date, required: true
    },
    gender: {
        type: String, enum: ['M', 'F'], required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: String, required: true
    }
  });
```

The query I'm trying to do is:

```
    Patient.
        find({name: { $gt: 'bob' }}).
        lean().
        sort('name surname').
        exec()
        .then(function (data) {
          //send data 
        })
        .catch(next);
```

Is there something I'm missing?

**---------------------EDIT---------------------**

Ok, didn't think at all about case sensitivity! ::embarassed::
In fact the query is returning the right result, as all my entries begin with an upper case letter.
Now the question is: should I enforce the database to only have uppercase or lowercase entries? (maybe using a validator hook) or is there a way to do a case insensitive $gt comparison?